# Inject the same bean instance into two other beans

Tags: spring

I wish to inject the same EntityManagerFactory instance into two of my spring beans.

I try:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-app"/>   
</bean>      

<bean id="serverDAO"
    class="com.ehcachedemo.dao.ServerDAO">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testServerDAO"
    class="com.ehcachedemo.test.TestServerDAO">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

But at runtime, two difference EntityManagerFactory instances are injected.  Any tips?  Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that these instances are different?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the default spring-managed bean is a singleton, your `entityManagerFactory` bean should *already* be the same instance in both DAOs.

You can make this explicit by adding `singleton="true"` to your `entityManagerFactory` bean definition.

So your bean definition should be:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    singleton="true">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-app"/>   
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can inject the same instance without limiting the number of instances to one?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` produces singletons by default.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not certain why you would want to.  Your DAO beans are themselves singletons by default, so the number of `EntityManagerFactory` instances would be 1 anyways.

Comment: Good comments.  The problem is if you instantiante more than one Spring IoC Container you get more than one EntityManagerFactory.  So the question should really be, how do you ensure only ever have one Spring IoC Container?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you're ending up with two IoC Containers, but the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-servicelocator) recommend using `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` if you're in an EJB environment. Otherwise, I would create a singleton class that provides consistent access to the the same container instance.